# Desvantagens para brasileiros usarem o Google App Engine

Tags: python, cloud

Eu já fiz alguns app e alguns testes com o Google App Engine.

Já li sobre várias de suas limitações, e algumas delas são um pouco
chatas, mas nada que me preocupe muito, pois como pretendo fazer algo novo, você já constrói pensando na limitações.

Apesar que nem todas as limitações são necessariamente coisas ruins,
exemplo seria o tempo de vida de uma request, que de qualquer forma, não
deve demorar muito mesmo (mesmo se for ajax), pois isso é limitado em outros ambientes/servidores, além de questões de usabilidade. Bom isso foi apenas um exemplo.

Como já trabalhei com outros tipos de bancos de dados (proprietário da empresa ou da linguagem) que não é no estilo SQL, o BigTable também não é tão difícil de se adaptar. Sei que tem outras alternativas, mas pelo que diz respeito a escalabilidade, BigTable é o rei. Claro que nem todo tipo de app fica fácil ou viável de fazer com bigtable, mas no caso das app que quero construir, isso também não é problema.

Mas tem alguns itens que me incomoda, preocupa um pouco, e gostaria de opiniões sobre os itens, sejam boas ou ruins:

Preço se em dólar, ou seja, com a volta dessa diferença cambial,
isso é bem preocupante.

Não ter data center no brasil, ou seja, por melhor que seja o data center, sempre vai ter um leg maior do que fosse no brasil, claro, tem muitos fatores envolvidos, e isso pode ser bom ou ruim.

Alguém lembra de mais alguma desvantagem?

Ou quer comentar algum dos pontos mencionados?

Alguém tem experiência para contar sobre o Google App Engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Desvantagens no Geral**

Há diversas desvantagens não só para os brasileiros,mas também para qualquer desenvolvedor que usa ela,algumas delas são :

> Apps por desenvolvedor - 10
>
> Tempo por `request` - 30 sec
>
> Arquivos por App - 3,000
>
> HTTP tamanho  - 10 MB
>
> Tamanho de item do DataStore - 1 MB
>
> Tamanho do código de aplicação - 150 MB

Ainda mais se você for verificar na lista de problemas conhecidos do GAE,você verá que é muitas,veja nestes [tópicos](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) falando sobre diversos problemas que se encontram pelo GAE.

Outras desvantagens são :

> Os desenvolvedores têm acesso somente a leitura pelo sistema de arquivos no Google App Engine.
>
> App Engine só pode executar um código chamado a partir de uma solicitação HTTP (exceto para as tarefas em segundo plano agendados).
>
> Os usuários podem fazer upload de módulos Python arbitrárias, mas somente se eles são puros-Python; módulos C e Pyrex não são suportados.
>
> Aplicações Java só podem utilizar um subconjunto (The JRE Class White List) das classes a partir da edição padrão JRE.
>
> Aplicações em Java não podem criar novos tópicos.

**Desvantagens para os Brasileiros**

Dando uma olhada na documentação oficial do Google App Engine,os custos em base das `API` do GAE,está mais ou menos o seguinte :

> Write  >> $0.10 por 100 mil operações,em reais equivale a  0.34 centavos.
>
> Read   >> $0.07 por 100 mil operações,em  reais equivale a 0,24 centavos.

OBS : Acima são o custo de métodos utilizados,por exemplo utilizando 100 mil operações com o método `Write` você paga $0.10 para o GAE.

Para ver quanto custava o minimo na questão de `host` por parte do GAE,eu utilizei a calculadora oficial deles de custos de serviços,que pode ser acessada [aqui](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

Colocando no mínimo os requisitos de upload,deu no total `$75,55`.Mas convertendo para reais,deu `R$257,66` para se hospedar com os requisitos mínimos.

Detalhe,você paga mensalmente este valor,e isto levando em consideração com o valor do dólar em relação a hoje,usei este [site](https://conversor-moedas.com/) para fazer a conversão e ele usa em base diária as conversões,o valor do dólar pode sempre aumentar conforme a reflexão do mercado internacional.

Ou seja,o custo é muito maior em relação a `host` por parte dos brasileiros,imagine com requisitos razoáveis de `upload`,o quanto não sairia.

Para ver a documentação inteira sobre os custos que o GAE cobra,dê uma olhada [aqui](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing).

**Conclusão**

Para mim ainda há mais desvantagens do que vantagens para nós brasileiros usarmos o Google App Engine,por não somente fatores econômicos mas ainda há outros fatores em questão de desenvolvimento através dele próprio.
O GAE ainda é novo em certos requisitos,somente agora conseguiu prover a base a `MySQL`por exemplo,mas mesmo assim,ainda há muito a melhorar,pois suas `API` ainda são limitas as tarefas que se quer muitas vezes não há um suporte bom para tal.

Comment: "Apps por desenvolvedor - 10", esse item não é uma limitação da conta gratuita? Mesmo se não for, basta ter mais de um celular, claro tem o inconveniente de ter mais de uma conta no google. Eu sei que o google não se importa se uma  mesma pessoa tenha mais de uma conta, eu por exemplo tenho 2 GAE. Sei disse pelas palavras de um próprio engenheiro do google, que deu uma palestra na python brasil de Curitiba, faz tempo, mas acho que ainda é assim.

Comment: A limitações técnicas, eu conheço várias, não todas óbvio, mas isso ainda não seria um grande problema para o tipo de app que gostaria de fazer, queria  saber mais questões práticas, que você só percebe fazendo.
Mesmo assim muito útil suas explicações, obrigado.

Comment: Ah, você tem alguma experiência prática com o GAE, mesmo se for pequena? 
Entendi seus pontos e concordo com a maioria deles, mas quando um dos requisitos essências é escalabidade, não se pagaria? Tipo, pela grande capacidade e facilitade
de escalar aplicações com GAE?

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net Sim neste quesito de escalabilidade você paga para ter melhorias em seus serviços.Pois em questão de request você só pode ter 500 requests por segundo,caso quiser mais,terá que paga.Mas há outros recursos como administração de fácil entendimento e relatórios por parte do GAE que fazem para você de graça.

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net Um dos reais problemas mesmo de se usar o GAE e que qualquer desenvolvedor logo percebe é de que conforme seu site vai se expandindo,você terá que gastar mais com as questões de host e de requisitos técnicos para manter o seu site.